# Laravel - Scheduled, Long Running Tasks. High Memory

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, system-administration

I'm currently writing an application in Laravel and am setting up some scheduled tasks that will be run periodically (artisan commands) -- maybe once or twice a month.  These tasks grab some CSV files using CURL, parse them, and import them into my local MySQL database.

However, a couple of these of these CSV files are quite large -- around 500,000 lines each.  So I have run into some memory issues.

Obviously I can increase the memory in my VM, but i'm wondering how what other practices I can implement to ensure that I don't run out of memory.  If I try to parse the files in chunks, rather than all at once, will each chunk be treated as a separate system process?  Or will it still be treated as one long execution for the server?

EDIT: My current approach.  I'm using [League CSV](http://csv.thephpleague.com/) for the Parsing.

```
protected $offset = 1;
protected $parse_chunk = 10000;

public function parse() 
{
     $this->data = [];
     $this->reader->setOffset($this->offset)->setLimit($this->parse_chunk)->fetchAll(function($row, $offset) {
            array_push($this->data, array_combine($this->keys, $row));
            $this->offset = $offset;
     });
}
```

So currently, the above fetches the first 10000 rows, and does the processing I need, which stores them in  a new `$data` array.  This data then gets passed to a Import Class, but my scripts are timing out in the parsing currently.

So the above works, but if I put that within a `while` loop to access all 500,000 records, then it uses too much memory.

Should I be dispatching each chunk to a queue which gets processed in the background?

EDIT: Added Benchmarks

I spent some time testing how long different processes take.  The Parsing had interesting results.  Keep in mind, this is JUST parsing.  So it is not being stored in the DB, but it is being stored in an Array in Memory.

```
Parsing 1000 records: .017 seconds
Parsing 10,000 records: .188 seconds
Parsing 100,000 records: 2.273 seconds
Parsing 500,000 records: Never completes.
```

I'm using the code above to execute this.  What might cause the parsing to take so long (or perhaps fail) at 500,000 records?

Comment: Maybe install php 7, it eats a lot less memory when dealing with arrays-assuming you haven't already.

Comment: @Mihai thanks for the suggestion, I'll certainly consider that.  But I'm more looking for the best practices in this sort of situation.  How are these sorts of large data sets usually handled?

Comment: Are you loading whole file into memory?

Comment: @chba I've added some code to demonstrate my current approach

Comment: Multiple chunks may only sum up and create same and even more memory consumption. I think it is because you just "concatenate" results. Clean allocated memory after each chunk and handle it from beginning to end separately. Do not yield all the results and then store them, if it is not crucial. So, in this way you do not need separate queue tasks.

Comment: @chba thanks for that  I have revised it some, an tried to free up memory after each iteration.  However, the parsing and inserting of 530,000 records is taking about 3.5 mins.  Does that seem reasonable?

Comment: @chba and i try and run the whole process twice, time second time takes over twice as long as the first

Comment: Hard to imagine what is going on without whole picture. Do time measurements for parsing inserting etc. Then you will have bigger picture of what is going on. Might be you are making your parser to open file read for each chunk. Without seeing bigger picture it is hard to tell.

Comment: @chba ok fair enough. I'll run some tests and see where I'm losing time. Thanks.

Comment: @chba I ran some tests and posted the results above

Comment: you have to upload data by parts, may be using crontab, I have developed a similar app with pure php and work fine.

Comment: "Never completes" returns error? What happens? Does process have no time limit?